# Access promise resolve in on click handler in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, es6-promise

This use case has three steps:
1.Make API call to check if record exists 
2.If record exists, then ask user if they want to add it to a group 
3.If user clicks ok on the displayed modal where we ask them, continue with another network request.

I am trying to get User Input using a modal confirm written in a custom component and based on the fact if user clicks Ok or cancel, I want to make a network request.

I cannot get access to the promise resolve function, even if I assign it to a variable that is accessible by the "onClick" handler.

I've already tried to access the promise resolve function inside the onClick handler of the button that the user clicks. It turns out to be undefined.

**getUserResponse is sent as an argument to another function that exists in a separate JS file where all network calls are made. It is being called there after the record has been found to exist as a result of an API call**

```
let outsideResolve;
const getUserResponse = async () => {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      outsideResolve = resolve;
    });
  };

const confirmAddRecord = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //resolve the promise after the button click
    outsideResolve(); //error: outsideResolve is not a function
    };

return (
      <div>
        <p>Record Exists would you like to add them to the group?</p>
        <button onClick={confirmAddRecord}>Add Existing record !</button>
      </div>
    );


*********************************
in another file (networkCalls.js), getUserResponse is sent 
as an argument to a method called in the file summarized above
try {
    let userResponse = await getUserResponse();
    console.log(userResponse);
    //Do more stuff after the reply comes in
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

I have created a codeSandbox to re-create the problem in more detail: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/promisemodal-tke67

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly - main issue that you had is getting access to info from your original (`check if user exists`) API call. Based on that `return`ed info you wanted to take another action.

Please see my solution to your issue (tested on your `codesandbox`). Here is a fork of it with implementation (https://codesandbox.io/s/promisemodal-z2r5i)

`index.js` below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {
  ADD_NEW_RECORD,
  MAKE_API_CALL_AFTER_RECORD_CHECK
} from "./networkCalls";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModelOpen] = useState(false);
  const [infoFromCreateRecord, setInfoFromCreateRecord] = useState({});

  const createRecord = () => {
    ADD_NEW_RECORD(isModalOpen, setIsModelOpen, setInfoFromCreateRecord);
  };

  const confirmAddRecord = () => {
    MAKE_API_CALL_AFTER_RECORD_CHECK(infoFromCreateRecord);
    setIsModelOpen(false);
  };

  const renderModal = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Record Exists would you like to add them to the group?</p>
        <button onClick={confirmAddRecord}>Add Existing record !</button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Add record by pressing this button</p>
      <button onClick={createRecord}>Create record </button>
      {isModalOpen ? renderModal() : ""}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

`networkCalls.js` below

```
export const ADD_NEW_RECORD = (
  isModalOpen,
  setIsModalOpen,
  setInfoFromCreateRecord
) => {
  //checking from an API of record exists

  const checkIfRecordExists = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Record Exists");
      resolve("Record Exists");
    }, 1000);
  });

  //record exists, ask the user if they want to add them to the group
  checkIfRecordExists.then(() => {
    setInfoFromCreateRecord({
      importantInfo: "record does exits"
    });
    setIsModalOpen(!isModalOpen);
  });
};

export const MAKE_API_CALL_AFTER_RECORD_CHECK = infoFromCreateRecord => {
  // do some stuff with the info from the first API call

  const doSomethingAfterRecordCheck = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(infoFromCreateRecord);
      resolve("User got added to the group!");
    }, 1000);
  });

  doSomethingAfterRecordCheck.then(() => {
    console.log("do something after adding the user to the group");
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel network.js should only return promise and those promises should resolved in your main component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { ADD_NEW_RECORD } from "./networkCalls";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModelOpen] = useState(false);

  let createRecordPromsie = null;
  const createRecord = () => {
    createRecordPromsie = ADD_NEW_RECORD();
    createRecordPromsie.then(data => {
      setIsModelOpen(true);
    });
  };

  const getUserResponse = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });

  const confirmAddRecord = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //resolve the promise after the button click
    console.log("Added Existing record");
    getUserResponse.then(data => {
      setIsModelOpen(false);
    }); //this turns out to be undefined
  };

  const renderModal = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Record Exists would you like to add them to the group?</p>
        <button onClick={confirmAddRecord}>Add Existing record !</button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Add record by pressing this button</p>
      <button onClick={createRecord}>Create record </button>
      {isModalOpen ? renderModal() : ""}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Network.js

```
export const ADD_NEW_RECORD = async () => {
  //checking from an API of record exists

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Record Exists");
      resolve("Record Exists");
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```